# Check if every elemnt from a form is filled JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

I have a form with all types of form elemnts and I have a code that should run through every single one of the elemnts and check their value after the submit button is clicked. Unfortunatelly, this code doesn't work completely. What I mean is that if I don't enter any value in the input, it will print the message, but if I enter some text in it, we go to the else statement, without checking the other.

Could somebody tell me why?

```
if($('form.registration-form :input').val() == '')
    {
        // Print Error Message
    }
else
    {
        // Do something else
    }
```

Comment: trim() it as well, maybe someone enters spaces, which count as blank characters

Comment: `$('form.registration-form :input')` returns all form controls but adding `.val()` only returns the value of the first in the collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method for this:

```
var emptyElements = $('form.registration-form :input').filter( function() {
    return this.value === '';
});

if( emptyElements.length === 0 ) {
  // all IS filled in
} else {
  // all is NOT filled in
}
```

```js
$('#submit').click(function(){
    var emptyElements = $('form.registration-form :input').filter( function() {
        return this.value === '';
    });
    
    if( emptyElements.length === 0 ) {
        alert('All Filled');
    } else {
        alert('1 or more not filled')
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" class="registration-form">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Check">
</form>
```

Comment: I'd make 2 adjustment. 1: Change `$( this ).val() != '';` to `this.value != '';`. 2: I'd make it `this.value === '';` then `if(notEmpty.length === 0)`. It remove the need to create an other jQuery object. Note that I would change to var name as well since it doesn't make any sens. +1 anyway.

Comment: Oh, thank you. You saved me a lot of time searchin arount the Net. :)

Comment: I know, I changed the `!= ''` to `=== ''`. The var name just doesn'T make sense.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon yes, you are correct! Thanks. Updated again. Much better now

Comment: Here, I made a fiddle, you can integrate it in your answer if you want : http://jsfiddle.net/91pqmn0h/1/

Comment: @TheMetalMonster don't forget to accept answers if they was helpful to you ;)